# Gazebo headless crashes when starting pr2.launch

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, pr2-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am just trying to work out "pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Running a realtime joint controller". But Gazebo crashes when tried launching pr2. So I ran gazebo headless and it still crashes. Here is the backtrace.

```
gazebo: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float, int Size = 4, int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0012e416 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0012e416 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x01c6f941 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x01c72e42 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x01c688e8 in __assert_fail () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x07d324ab in plain_array (this=0xb0b22898, parent=0xb0b21238)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:69
#5  DenseStorage (this=0xb0b22898, parent=0xb0b21238)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:102
#6  PlainObjectBase (this=0xb0b22898, parent=0xb0b21238)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:381
#7  Matrix (this=0xb0b22898, parent=0xb0b21238)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:276
#8  Quaternion (this=0xb0b22898, parent=0xb0b21238)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:256
#9  Identity (this=0xb0b22898, parent=0xb0b21238)
    at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:112
#10 PointCloud (this=0xb0b22898, parent=0xb0b21238)
    at /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/include/pcl-1.1/pcl/point_cloud.h:81
#11 gazebo::GazeboRosCamera::GazeboRosCamera (this=0xb0b22898, 
    parent=0xb0b21238)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_r---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
os_camera.cpp:66
#12 0x07d32714 in gazebo::NewGazeboRosCamera (entity=0xb0b21238)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_camera.cpp:61
#13 0x001a880e in gazebo::ControllerFactory::NewController (classname=..., 
    parent=0xb0b21238)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:65
#14 0x00178406 in gazebo::Sensor::LoadController (this=0xb0b21238, 
    node=0xb0e2e378)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/sensors/Sensor.cc:218
#15 0x00179286 in gazebo::Sensor::Load (this=0xb0b21238, node=0xb0e2e260)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/sensors/Sensor.cc:85
#16 0x00e48672 in gazebo::Body::LoadSensor (this=0x85f05c8, node=0xb0e2e260)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/physics/Body.cc:623
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#17 0x00e50bf4 in gazebo::Body::Load (this=0x85f05c8, node=0xb0e2d6a8)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/physics/Body.cc:247
#18 0x0101b08c in gazebo::ODEBody::Load (this=0x85f05c8, node=0xb0e2d6a8)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/physics/ode/ODEBody.cc:87
#19 0x001dbf0b in gazebo::Model::LoadBody (this=0xb0e3d9e0, node=0xb0e2d6a8)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Model.cc:922
#20 0x001dca5e in gazebo::Model::LoadPhysical (this=0xb0e3d9e0, 
    node=0xb19e5f00)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Model.cc:1286
#21 0x001e2685 in gazebo::Model::Load (this=0xb0e3d9e0, node=0xb19e5f00, 
    removeDuplicate=true)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Model.cc:217
#22 0x001b0767 in gazebo::World::LoadModel (this=0x816fff8, node=0xb19e5f00, 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    parent=0x0, removeDuplicate=false, initModel=true)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/World.cc:583
#23 0x001b97f2 in gazebo::World::LoadEntities (this=0x816fff8, 
    node=0xb19e5f00, parent=0x0, removeDuplicate=<value optimized out>, 
    initModel=<value optimized out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/World.cc:460
#24 0x001b9771 in gazebo::World::LoadEntities (this=0x816fff8, 
    node=0xb0d3a418, parent=0x0, removeDuplicate=true, initModel=true)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/World.cc:468
#25 0x001b98f9 in gazebo::World::ProcessEntitiesToLoad (this=0x816fff8)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/World.cc:509
#26 0x001eb86f in gazebo::Simulator::MainLoop (this=0x814d918)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:491
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#27 0x0809d3ce in main (argc=3, argv=0xbfffed84)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.2/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/gazeboros.cpp:2607
```

Hope someone could help me.

Thanks

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11175/gazebo-headless-crashes-when-starting-pr2.launch/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2011-09-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-12**:
yes, in that case, the bug applies.  I've checked in a patch in trunk, will make a release soon.  It would be great if you (or anyone with a 32bit machine) can please test out the patch by compiling from source?  Thanks.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2011-09-12**:
yes 32bit linux. I'm running ros-electric, in Ubuntu 11.04

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-12**:
Are you running on 32bit linux?  if so, might be a bug: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I too had this error with electric on Ubuntu 11.04 32bit. hsu's fix in simulator_gazebo/trunk remedies the problem.

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2011-09-27**:
Thank you all for the replies. With the 1.4.5, it crashes with "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::RenderingAPIException'". So, I assume it is a problem with my graphics. Then, when I ran gazebo headless, it does not crash but the pr2 controllers do not get loaded.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-21**:
ah, right, the deb's hasn't propagated out yet, right now it's on 1.4.3.  You can check the release status at http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html, look for simulator_gazebo for your platform.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-09-21**:
Just released 11 hours ago? I encountered the problem after a fresh synaptic install of electric on a fresh install of ubuntu 11.04 immediately before I posted.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-20**:
the patch has been released, please check your /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt to see if rosbuild_make_distribution(#) >= 1.4.4.  Let me know if the problem still persists.